# Groovy - read file, modify its content and return it back

Tags: groovy

I'm wondering what's the best way to read a file (that I get as an argument), 
modify a specific line in it (iterate over the all the line until I'll find the one I need)
and finally, save the new modified file instead of the old one.

Regards,
Igor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to write to a temporary file, then rename the temprorary file to overwrite the original:

```
// Path to the original file
def infile = 'in.txt'

// Create a temp file
def tmpFile = File.createTempFile( 'new', 'tmp' )

tmpFile.withWriter { w ->

    // for each line in the input file
    new File( infile ).eachLine { line ->

        // Modify the line if required
        if( line.endsWith( '2' ) ) {
            line = 'Modified'
        }

        // Write the line out to the temp file
        w << line << '\n'
    }
}

// Then rename the temp file to overwrite the original
tmpFile.renameTo( infile )
```

Comment: A quick question - do I need to delete the "infile" at the end?

Comment: No, it should be moved to the name of `infile` (I've tested it on OS X, and this is the case -- Windows can get a little funky with moving files)

Comment: This is exactly my dilemma, I'm in Win environment :) never mind, I check it out later on.
Thanks for the quick and useful answers.